# MySQL won't insert certain field

Tags: php, mysql

This code won't work. I've had everything echoed and it displays fine on the webpage, as in, all the data is collected fine. What isn't working is inserting it into the MySQL table.

This same query, without the archive insertion, works fine. But for some reason MySQL doesn't want to insert my archive copy. The archive column exists and I've double checked and everything. Archive was created as ARCHIVE TEXT,. Why is this? Workaround? No error is printed.

```
  $url = $_GET["url"];

  $data = get_meta_tags($url);

  echo $url = $url;
  echo $tags = $data ['keywords'];     // php documentation
  echo $desc = $data ['description'];  // a php manual
  $archive = strip_tags(file_get_contents($url));

  include("../library/config.php");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO URLs(url, description, tags, archive) VALUES ('$url', '$desc', '$tags', '$archive')", $link);
  echo mysql_error($link);
```

Comment: What does `$archive` contain when you output it?

Comment: What is the content of `$archive`?  Does it contain a single-quote character?  Also, why aren't you sanitizing input?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` - use it

Comment: The values in $archive do sound like they may hold the key - especially if some kind soul wrote "don't" in it :) see the single quote :)

Comment: archive contains any URL's contents. for example, a CNN.com article. The entire page's contents, but only the text. The HTML tags are stripped.

Comment: will sanitize and make the code shiny once it's finalized this is just scratch work for now.

Comment: Ditto to mysqli_real_escape_string. As in $archive = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags(file_get_contents($url)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain why it's not giving you an error, because it should be!  You're taking the entire contents of an unknown URL and attempting to insert it into a table column.  You should be escaping it first...

```
$archive = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(file_get_contents($url)), $link);
```

Basically, this will escape quote characters, correctly according to encoding of your table.  If the mysql_connect is happening from the included ../library/config.php file, you should have this escape after that line of code, since it references the $link connection.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I've used your edit and even a alternate form, $archive = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags(file_get_contents($url)));, but it's still not inserting.

Comment: you have your argument order reversed.  $link should be the second argument.

Comment: actually, I see the mysqli_real_escape_string has $link as the first argument.  But you are using the procedural mysql library, not the object oriented library, so anything mysqli_ will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Does $archive have a single-quote character in it?  If so, you've closed the string for the insert statement.  Look into using bind variables.

Better yet, use PDO.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/